# The method putExtra(String, String) is undefined for the type PendingIntent

Tags: android

whether it's possible to use putExtra method in pendingintent

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass `intent` in initializing `PendingIntent` object. you  can call `putExtra(string,string)` methods on `intent` object instead, something like below

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(mContext,activity2.class);
    **intent.putExtra("string","string");** // call putExtra with intent
    pendingIntent =  PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, 0); // here we are passing intent object. you can also call getBR or GetService , but you will always passing intent in the method.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code: by using ***Intent***, ***putextra*** and ***PendingIntent***-----
***Intent*** notificationIntent = new Intent(context,AllContacts.class);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String sDate = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + (c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "-" +c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) ;
notificationIntent.***putExtra***("searcheddob", sDate);
***PendingIntent*** contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `putExtra` on the intent from which you then create the `PendingIntent`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

First Use `Intent`. Put `Extars` values to it.
Invoke that Intent to your `PendingIntent`. Simple solution.

Hope you get what exactly I am saying. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it using Intent and PendingIntent as:

```
Intent alarmintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity2.class);
    alarmintent.putExtra("title", "Title of our Notification");
    alarmintent.putExtra("note", "Description of our  Notification");
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ID, alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
```

I used it for setting Alarm in device. Hope this will help you.